# Networkx add_weighted_edges_from return strange result

Tags: python, networkx

I'm trying to init a Networkx.MultiDiGraph with weight for all edges.

I have a dictionary as follow:

```
edges = {(Node1, Node2, 1.0): <some_object>,
         (Node1, Node3, 2.0): <some_object>,
         ...}
```

I'm running the following code:

```
nx_graph: nx.MultiDiGraph = nx.MultiDiGraph()
nx_graph.add_nodes_from(nodes.values())           # This works fine.
nx_graph.add_weighted_edges_from(edges.keys())
nx.set_edge_attributes(nx_graph, edges, 'edge')
```

but for some unknown reason, nx_graph contain the following edges:

```
print(nx_graph.edges)
>>>[(Node1, Node2, 0), (Node1, Node3, 0), ...]
```

and the edges doesn't have any attributes at all.

Does someone know why this is happening and how to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you give some actual examples instead of `<some_object>`?

Answer (score 0):

I know, it's annoying for me too, but `nx` just has too many intertwining methods to access data of edges. You just used an incorrect way. `G.edges` lists all the edges, nothing more. (I use `G` as `nx_graph` for simplicity)

In order to list edges together with attributes use `G.edges.data()` or `G.edges(data=True)`.

Remark: in order to list edges with specific attribute attached, use `G.edges.data(<attr>)` (as tuples with corresponding attributes attached to the last item) or `nx.get_edge_attributes(G, weight')` (as dictionary that maps edges to attributes).

Comment: Thanks mate, that was helpful, But didn't solve the main problem...

Answer (score 0):

The guy above me was right, i did print the edges wrong.
But that wasn't the problem, that was a symptom of my main problem: `Networkx.add_weighted_edges()` doesn't defined well for `nx.MultiDiGraph`.

i'll explain: while using `Networkx.add_weighted_edges()`, the `ebunch` parameter ([see documentation here](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9/reference/generated/networkx.DiGraph.add_weighted_edges_from.html))
using the triplet `(source, target, weight)` for adding an edge with weight.
Meanwhile, in `nx.MultiDiGraph`, every edge defined with `(source, target, unique_key)`.
So, `Networkx.add_weighted_edges()` doesn't reference the `unique_key` parameter in the edge, and that was the cause to my problem.

To solve this, i use the following code:

First, i changed `edges.keys()` so it will contain the keys of every edge:

```
edges = {(Node1, Node2, key1): <some_object>,
         (Node1, Node3, key2): <some_object>,
         ...}
```

Then, i used the following code:

```
edges_weights = {(Node1, Node2, key1): 1.0,
                 (Node1, Node3, key2): 2.0,
                 ...}

nx_graph: nx.MultiDiGraph = nx.MultiDiGraph()
nx_graph.add_nodes_from(nodes.values())         
nx_graph.add_edges_from(edges.keys())
nx.set_edge_attributes(nx_graph, edges_weights, 'weight')
nx.set_edge_attributes(nx_graph, edges, '<attribute_name>')
```

And that works fine for me.